# Cannot set background-image to repeating-linear-gradient in code behind

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

In my code, I want to add a repeating-linear-gradient to my `div` from my code behind. At the moment, I am trying to set this by the following code:

```
_div.Style.Add("background-image", "repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(0,100,200,.5),rgba(0,100,200,.5) 1px,transparent 1px,transparent 1px,rgba(0,100,200,.5) 1px)");
```

But the code has no effect on the div itself. I have been able to change the `display` with similar code:

```
_div.Style.Add("display", "inherit");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Here is the `HTML` for the `div`

```
<div id="_div" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="_Label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Here is the `CSS` for the `div`

```
#output_div {
    display: none;    
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    /*Below line works, but would like to set it dynamically on the server side*/
    /*    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,100,200,.3), rgba(0,100,200,.3) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 1px, rgba(0,100,200,.3) 1px);*/

    background-size: 4px 4px;
}
```

Comment: please full example i mean with html please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try with following approach,

```
_div.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(0,100,200,.5),rgba(0,100,200,.5) 1px,transparent 1px,transparent 1px,rgba(0,100,200,.5) 1px)");
```

That way, style attribute will be rendered to the output HTML.

**Update**
You can also try adding a specific CSS class.

```
.myBackgroundImg {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,100,200,.3), rgba(0,100,200,.3) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 1px, rgba(0,100,200,.3) 1px);
}
```

Then you can apply it in the code behind.

```
 _div.Attributes.Add("class", "myBackgroundImg");
```

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't even display the div, let alone the result I want.

Comment: @Hayden so your Div isn't even rendered to the client? What's the HTML source like in the browser?

Comment: I am going to try and make a new CSS sheet, link it, and see if the changes you've suggested actually happen, because for some reason now, it isn't recognizing that I got rid of display:none in the CSS

Comment: So I managed to get the div rendering again, but it still wasn't doing what I wanted, so I tried your second option, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line -

```
_div.Style.Add("background", "repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,100,200,.5) , rgba(0,100,200,.5) 1px,transparent 1px,transparent 1px,rgba(0,100,200,.5) 1px)")
```

You may have to use ScriptManager & UpdatePanel also.